# SD card suddenly locked

Tags: windows-10, fat32

I have a strange thing going on, and would like to know understand how this works, and how this can happen. I've been struggling a long time with it.

I use an SD card Formatted at FAT32 4096 cluster size. Sometimes, random the device locks the SD Card.

Inserting it into the PC, Windows says it is not locked.

Putting it back in the device it says Locked.

Formatting it FAT32, slow, 4096 cluster size and the locked status is removed.

I've tried some things, also on recommedation of the manufacuter, format with diskpart, set cluster size, programm it in such a way the PLC processor is less occupied but so far it is unsuccefull, change brand of sd card, change size,

To deal with the problem i think i need to know the problem. Tried to read the SD Specification but that's quit a challange to understand.

What I don't understand how it can be that the PLC says it is locked, and the PC not.

Manufacturer says it might have something to do with the offset, but i checked it and it is as described by the manufacturer.

If there are any unsuccesfull writing it should never set the Locked Bit, i assume. Only files will get corrupt,

Please help,

Comment: Many SD cards have a write-protect switch on them. Is it possible this switch has been intermittently set/unset without you meaning to do so?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It is a micro SD card (did not tell you) so it holds no switch.